# VirtualBox Host only network don't work Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-adapter, bridge

I have a problem configuring a Host Only network in VirtualBox, when I give a static address to the VM I can't ping from Host to VM and neither from VM to host and when I give an automatic IP it just give an unusable 169.254.x.x IP.
The host is on Windows 7 and the VM is on Debian Jessie, both are 64-bits.

Here's the ifconfig of the Virtual machine as well as the interfaces file:

[image: ifconfig]
[image: interfaces]

Here you can see Windows' ipconfig:

[image: ipconfig all windows IP]
[image: ipconfig all host only networking]

and finally the ping tests (Host to the left, VM to the right):

[image: ping test]

Here's what I tried:

- changing both IPs using both command lines and UI
- Changing the mask
- Reinstalling VirtualBox
- Remove and recreate the Host Only adapter
- Recreate the VM from scratch (still the same problem)
- Changing VM from static IP to dhcp (both while offline and while online) (it gives an 169.254.x.x IP)
- Changing adapter from static to auto on Host (adapter only get an IPV6 while offline and give an unreachable IPV4 while online)

Every time I changed the IP on the Host I did an `ipconfig /release` followed by an `ipconfig /renew`
Every time I changed the IP on the VM I rebooted it.
I took care that both always were in the same network when I changed the IPs.
I'm out of idea, how can I make the VM and the host communicate together? I even tried a simple bridge and it has the exact same problems.

Comment: Windows Firewall blocks ICMP echo by default. Try disabling it temporarily and check to see if the connectivity problem persists. If not, then create a rule to allow ICMP echo packets so you can have connectivity between the host and VM without disabling the firewall.

Comment: @Larssend it did not work, I still get "Destination host unreachable"